# how to close , shut down a WPF application when user need to closed it

Tags: wpf

how i can write a closed function for our wpf application
in Window application  we can simply use application.exit();
are any way to closed a wpf application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
 Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

and aslo pls verify the ShutdownMode in the application(App.xaml)